# Have no clue what has gone wrong here. I am sure this is the correct syntax, and I have checked for typos

Tags: python

```
# Lists.
months = [6, 2, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4]
weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

# Functions for algorithm.
def yearcode(y):
    """generate year-code using algorithm"""
    y = y % 100
    y = y + (y / 4) % 7
    return round(y)

def monthcode(m):
    """get month number from month-list"""
    return months[monthin - 1]

def daycode(d):
    """simplify day number for efficiency"""
    return d % 7

# Inputs.
dayayin = int(input("What Day in the Month?"))
monthin = int(input("What Month? E.g.- January is 1"))
yearin = int(input("What Year?"))

# Define variables for functions.
yearout = yearcode(yearin)
monthout = monthcode(monthin)
dayout = daycode(dayin)

# Final Add-Up and Output.
result = (dayout + monthout + yearout) % 7
print(weekdays[result])
```

The Error is: "ParseError: bad input on line 17" The purpose of this program is to give the day of the week for any date. As you can see it is not happy with how I have given the purpose of the function for my benefit. I really feel like I am missing something here.

Here is the Improved and Working Version (Thanks for the help!)

```
# Lists.
months = [6, 2, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4]
weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",  "Saturday"]

# Fruitful Functions for Algorithm.
def yearcode(y):
    """Year Code Generator Algorithm"""
    y = y % 100
    y = y + (y / 4) % 7
    return int(round(y))

def monthcode(m):
    """Retrieve Month Number from Month List"""
    return months[m - 1]

def daycode(d):
    """Simplify Day Input for Efficiency"""
    return d % 7

# Inputs.
dayin = int(input("What Day in the Month?"))
monthin = int(input("What Month? E.g.- January is 1"))
yearin = int(input("What Year?"))

# Define Variables for Functions.
yearout = yearcode(yearin)
monthout = monthcode(monthin)
dayout = daycode(dayin)

# Final Add-Up and Output.
result = int((dayout + monthout + yearout) % 7)
print(weekdays[result])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could be getting an error because of issues mixing spaces an tabs.  Try to run your script with

```
python -t yourscript.py
```

and see if it tells you anything.

Perhaps, it would be easier to just use the builtin function in the [`calendar`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.weekday) module.

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.weekday(2013,2,18)
0
>>> calendar.day_name[calendar.weekday(2013,2,18)]
'Monday'
```

As a side note, running your code, I don't get a ParseError -- I get a `NameError` because `dayin` isn't defined.  Maybe you didn't mean to name it `dayayin`?

Comment: damn, but I do get a parse error on that line. cheers for the heads-up on the typo though.

Comment: @user2080262 -- After fixing that, there's an `IndexError` which crops up because you're using a non-integer (`float`) as your index -- There are probably other bugs too.

Comment: @user2080262 -- Also, try running it as `python -t yourscript.py` to check for mixing spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using "m" not "monthin" in the body of the monthcode function

Answer (score 1):

Some simple errors I see already:

Probably a typo using the variable `dayayin` instead of  `dayin`

```
dayayin = int(input("What Day in the Month?"))
...
dayout = daycode(dayin)
```

In the function `monthcode`, where does `mothin`comes from?

```
def monthcode(m):
    """get month number from month-list"""
    return months[monthin - 1]
```

**Edit:**
After fixing these, and making `result` an integer

```
result = int((dayout + monthout + yearout) % 7)
```

the script runs, but there is still some off-by one error in your code. When I enter my date of birth (19/05/1978) it returns Thursday, but I am born on a Friday.

Comment: Also change `result` to `int((dayout + monthout + yearout) % 7)`

Comment: thanks, i will tweak it.

Comment: that might be because the rounding isn't working properly. If the answer is (in yearcode) something.5, then it needs to round up. rounding down isn't a problem, but that could be it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with BioGeek

> the script runs, but there is still some off-by one error in your
>   code. When I enter my date of birth (19/05/1978) it returns Thursday,
>   but I am born on a Friday.

Your working version appears to be one day off compared to several online calculators. e.g.

```
What Day in the Month?19
What Month? E.g.- January is 15
What Year?1942
Monday
```

But other calculators show it as `Tuesday`.

Comment: it's all fixed now, works perfectly ty

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting that line and re-entering it by hand? I've often seen people, especially Mac users, enter invisible Unicode characters (alt+space, if I remember correctly). This could be the source of your problem.

Comment: done it, still an error

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in my other answer, when I entered my date of birth it gave a wrong answer.

More specifically, your code gives correct answers when you try a date in the year 2013, but as soon as you try to use it for dates further back or in the future, there is a 81.76%  probability that it returns a wrong answer.  Among others, it doesn't take into account leap years, nor does it compensate for dates not in the 21st century.

Trying to figure out where you went wrong I needed to know which algorithm you were using. Googeling for the list `[6, 2, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4]` landed me on [this page](http://www.kungfoomanchu.com/z-creations/mentalcalculationofdate.pdf) (pdf) which had a very detailed description, but also had several additional steps then you currently have in your algorithm.

So here is my implementation of that algorithm. I checked it against the `calendar`solution provided by [mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson) for every date since the beginning of the Gregorian calendar till 2300.

```
import datetime
import calendar

months = [6, 2, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4]
weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
            "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
centuries = {17: 5,
             18: 3,
             19: 1,
             20: 0,
             21: -2,
             22: -4}

def day_of_week_biogeek(day, month, year):
    # This algorithm is only valid for the Gregorian calendar
    # which began on September 14, 1752.
    if year <= 1752 and month <= 9 and day < 14:
        raise RuntimeError("This algorithm is only valid for the Gregorian " + \  
                           "calendar which began on September 14, 1752.")
    if year >= 2300:
        raise RuntimeError("This algorithm is only valid for the Gregorian " + \
                           "calendar up till December 31, 2299.")


    # Take multiples of 28 from the the last 2 digits of the year
    y = divmod(year, 100)[1] % 28

    # Add a quarter of the nearest multiple of 4 below the number,
    y += divmod(y, 4)[0]

    # Take away 7 or multiples of 7. This leaves us the year code
    y = y % 7

    # The code for the month from the table above
    m = months[month - 1]

    # If it is a leap year AND the month is January or February, subtract 1
    if is_leap_year(year) and month in [1,2]:
        m -= 1

    # Take away 7 or multiples of 7 from the day
    d = day % 7

    # Add the codes for the year, the month and the day
    result = y + m + d

    # Add 1 if the date is in the 1900s
    result += centuries[divmod(year, 100)[0]]

    # Take away 7 or multiples of 7
    result = result % 7

    # The final number indicates day of the week
    return weekdays[result]

def is_leap_year(year):
    # Leap years are the years evenly divisible by 4
    # unless it ends in 00 and is a multiple of 400
    if not year % 400:
        return True
    elif not year % 100:
        return False
    elif not year % 4:
        return True
    return False

# original code by user2080262
def yearcode(y):
    """Year Code Generator Algorithm"""
    y = y % 100
    y = y + (y / 4) % 7
    return int(round(y))

def monthcode(m):
    """Retrieve Month Number from Month List"""
    return months[m - 1]

def daycode(d):
    """Simplify Day Input for Efficiency"""
    return d % 7


def day_of_week_user2080262(dayin, monthin, yearin):
    yearout = yearcode(yearin)
    monthout = monthcode(monthin)
    dayout = daycode(dayin)
    result = int((dayout + monthout + yearout) % 7)
    return weekdays[result]

# alternate solution using builtin functions
def day_of_week_mgilson(day, month, year):
    """ See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14941764/50065"""
    c = calendar.weekday(year, month, day)
    return calendar.day_name[c]

def date_generator(day, month, year):
    """Convience function to return the next day"""
    d = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    while True:
        d += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        yield d.day, d.month, d.year


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # checking all days from the beginning of the Gregorian
    # calender till 2300
    methods = {'user2080262': day_of_week_user2080262,
               'BioGeek': day_of_week_biogeek}
    for user, func in methods.items():
        checked = 0
        wrong = 0
        d = date_generator(14, 9, 1752)
        for day, month, year in d:
            checked += 1
            if year == 2300:
                break
            if func(day, month, year) != day_of_week_mgilson(day, month, year):
                wrong += 1
        print("The code by {0} gives a wrong answer ".format(user) + \ 
              "{0:.2f}% of the time.".format((float(wrong)/checked)*100))
```